# How to retrieve object value from database stored as json

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have stored data in json format

```
        $data = [
            'applicant_name' => auth()->user()->name,
            'post_held' => getDesignation(auth()->user()->designation_id)->name,
            'department' => request('department')
        ];

        $leave = new Leave;

        $leave->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $leave->data = json_encode($data);

        $leave->save();
```

How can I retrieve them if I want to display applicant_name from data field?

I am trying -

```
        $leave = Leave::find($leave_id);

        return $leave->data['applicant_name'];
```

If I dd($leave) then it gives me

```
    "id" => 2
    "user_id" => 7
    "data" => "{"applicant_name":"Mousumi Roy","post_held":"Administrative Officer Judicial","department":"Computer"}"
    "created_at" => "2020-04-25 17:38:25"
    "updated_at" => "2020-04-25 17:38:25"
```

Comment: `$leave->data` looks like a JSON string, so have you tried using `json_decode()` and then accessing the values.

Comment: I am getting  "The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given."        - this error if I do like

Comment: So if it's an object, does `$leave->data->applicant_name` work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array casting for this, you can see in the doc:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

in your model, use

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Leave extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'data' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

then in your code, you don't need to use json_decode or json_encode, just:

```
        $leave = new Leave;
        $leave->data = $data;
        $leave->save();
```

And

```
        $leave = Leave::find($leave_id);
        return $leave->data['applicant_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

First You need to retrieve object for ex: `$leave` and then access to data with:

`$data = $leave->data` or `$data = $leave['data']`

but its encoded so try to decode that with `$decoded = json_decode($data)`

At the end you can access to `applicant_name` with `$decoded->applicant_name`